# Enable TLS 1.2 and disable SSL 3 on SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, tls-1.2

I know similar questions have been asked. What I'm asking for are concrete instructions on what to do, or not do, for my particular installation. I have some questions that I can't find the answer to, and I need some answers before I can install Microsoft's hotfix.

The goal is to disable SSL 3 on the machine by adding the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\Schannel\Protocols\SSL 3.0\Server\ - add value Enabled = 0`. However this causes SqlServerAgent to not start.

Running SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP3) build 10.50.6220.0 (X64).

[image]

Here's Microsoft's official download to enable TLS1.2 support: [link to microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server)

The page reads *First build that supports TLS 1.2 - 10.50.6542.0*. This is higher than my build number. Does it mean the hotfix only is compatible with builds from 10.50.6542 and up? And so my build is not supported?

If my build is supported, then I supposed I should install it. Then what happens next?

Comment: Then you enable TLS 1.2 and disable SSL 3 and see what happens and ask a question if you have problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to be compatible with TLS 1.2, you must be running SQL Server 2008 R2 version 10.50.6542.0 or later.

To get to that version level, you need to install Service Pack 3 for SQL Server 2008 R2, then install the hotfix from KB3144114 from https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/Hotfix/KbHotfix?kbnum=3144114&kbln=en-us which will update your SQL Server to v 10.50.6542.

Be aware, the above hotfix should never be installed on a production system unless you've extensively tested it in your test-environment first.

Comment: Link is dead.  I used this one and got TLS1.2 working in SQLSvr2008R2, v10.50.6560.0 (using this patch), and selecting **[x] SSL** and port 587 (TLS port).  Here's the link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3135244-tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server-e4472ef8-90a9-13c1-e4d8-44aad198cdbe