# Does SQL Server 2008 R2 10.50.6560.0 Support TLS 1.2?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

We recently upgraded a non-production SQL Server 2008 R2 system to SP3, and then Windows Updates installed the latest Security Update (10.50.6560.0).  I see that TLS 1.2 support for 2008 R2 is provided in 10.50.6542.0, but that update will not install on top of 6560.  Login attempts are failing and I can see in Event Viewer that the client is requesting TLS 1.2, but the server doesn't support it.

SSMS returns:

> ...(provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
>   (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10054)

System Event Log on server:

> Event ID 36874
>   An TLS 1.2 connection request was received from a remote client application, but none of the cipher suites supported by the client application are supported by the server. The SSL connection request has failed.

I have tried updating the various SQL clients on both client and server, enabling TLS 1.2 in the registry on the server (and rebooting), to no avail.  So now I'm beginning to think that build 6560 doesn't support it, and if that's the case, I have to uninstall it somehow so that I can install build 6542 first.

We have other servers running the same build that work fine, so I'm trying to find what's different about this server--no luck yet.

Comment: 6560 includes the fixes from 6542, so uninstalling the former to install the latter is not going to get you anywhere. This is not SQL Server but another component, likely SqlClient or .NET Framework. Did you install all applicable updates from the second and third tables [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server)? I don't think you'll get any of those by default from Windows Update.

Comment: [This answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/210730/10832) shows the required minimums for TLS 1.2 on SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build 10.50.6560.0 does support TLS 1.2.  I was able to resolve the problem by installing a new certificate from our CA.  Apparently the older certificates that are on the server are not capable of supporting TLS 1.2.

[TLS 1.2 support for Microsoft SQL Server](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server) includes information regarding the client and server versions that are required to support TLS 1.2.

Answer (score 0):

We have just moved to Exchange 2016 and our 2008 R2 servers were unable to send emails after that. I configured Database Mail for SSL and port 587 and gave it a trusted login but then found an error in the Eventlog that was to do with the system not being able to download a certificate. I therefore downloaded it manually and installed it and was able to send emails after that.

The certificate is:

http://ctldl.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/47BEABC922EAE80E78783462A79F45C254FDE68B.crt